# Laravel: Error in d3 js multiple line chart with dropdown selector

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I'm trying a multiple-line chart with a dropdown selector. I'm using JSON data. But the result is an error with:

1. In legend, not all classrooms are shown. The picture :

[image: picture]

2. Data and axes do not appear. The picture:

[image: picture]

Here's the code:

```js
function filterJSON(json, key, value) {
  var result = [];
  json.forEach(function(val, idx, arr) {
    if (val[key] == value) {

      result.push(val)
    }
  })
  return result;
}

// Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
var margin = {
    top: 50,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 160
  },
  width = 1000 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 550 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Parse the date / time


// Set the ranges
var x = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]).range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

// Define the axes
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
  .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
  .orient("left").ticks(5);

// Define the line
var classline = d3.svg.line()
  .interpolate("cardinal")
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(d.month);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d.value);
  });

// Adds the svg canvas
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
var data;
// Get the data
d3.json("https://api.npoint.io/f11e2edfeb742c8c882a", function(error, json) {

  json.forEach(function(d) {
    d.value = +d.value;
  });

  d3.select('#inds')
    .on("change", function() {
      var sect = document.getElementById("inds");
      var section = sect.options[sect.selectedIndex].value;

      data = filterJSON(json, 'year', section);


      //debugger

      data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.value = +d.value;
        //d.year = parseDate(String(d.year));
        d.active = true;
      });


      //debugger
      updateGraph(data);


      jQuery('h1.page-header').html(section);
    });

  // generate initial graph
  data = filterJSON(json, 'year', '2020');
  updateGraph(data);

});

var color = d3.scale.ordinal().range(["#48A36D", "#0096ff", "#ff007e"]);

function updateGraph(data) {


  // Scale the range of the data
  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
    return d.month;
  }));
  y.domain([d3.min(data, function(d) {
    return d.value;
  }), d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.value;
  })]);


  // Nest the entries by state
  dataNest = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) {
      return d.class;
    })
    .entries(data);


  var result = dataNest.filter(function(val, idx, arr) {
    return $("." + val.key).attr("fill") != "#ccc"
    // matching the data with selector status
  })


  var classroom = svg.selectAll(".line")
    .data(result, function(d) {
      return d.key
    });

  classroom.enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "line");

  classroom.transition()
    .style("stroke", function(d, i) {
      return d.color = color(d.key);
    })
    .attr("id", function(d) {
      return 'tag' + d.key.replace(/\s+/g, '');
    }) // assign ID
    .attr("d", function(d) {

      return classline(d.values)
    });

  classroom.exit().remove();

  var legend = d3.select("#legend")
    .selectAll("text")
    .data(dataNest, function(d) {
      return d.key
    });

  //checkboxes
  legend.enter().append("rect")
    .attr("width", 10)
    .attr("height", 10)
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", function(d, i) {
      return 0 + i * 15;
    }) // spacing
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
      return color(d.key);

    })
    .attr("class", function(d, i) {
      return "legendcheckbox " + d.key
    })
    .on("click", function(d) {
      d.active = !d.active;

      d3.select(this).attr("fill", function(d) {
        if (d3.select(this).attr("fill") == "#ccc") {
          return color(d.key);
        } else {
          return "#ccc";
        }
      })


      var result = dataNest.filter(function(val, idx, arr) {
        return $("." + val.key).attr("fill") != "#ccc"
        // matching the data with selector status
      })

      // Hide or show the lines based on the ID
      svg.selectAll(".line").data(result, function(d) {
          return d.key
        })
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .style("stroke", function(d, i) {
          return d.color = color(d.key);
        })
        .attr("d", function(d) {
          return classline(d.values);
        });

      svg.selectAll(".line").data(result, function(d) {
        return d.key
      }).exit().remove()

    })

  // Add the Legend text
  legend.enter().append("text")
    .attr("x", 15)
    .attr("y", function(d, i) {
      return 10 + i * 15;
    })
    .attr("class", "legend");

  legend.transition()
    .style("fill", "#777")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.key;
    });

  legend.exit().remove();

  svg.selectAll(".axis").remove();

  // Add the X Axis
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

  // Add the Y Axis
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("class", "axis-title")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("fill", "#5D6971")
    .text("Jumlah Siswa");
};

function clearAll() {
  d3.selectAll(".line")
    .transition().duration(100)
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      return null;
    });
  d3.select("#legend").selectAll("rect")
    .transition().duration(100)
    .attr("fill", "#ccc");
};

function showAll() {
  d3.selectAll(".line")
    .transition().duration(100)
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      return classline(d.values);
    });
  d3.select("#legend").selectAll("rect")
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
      if (d.active == true) {
        return color(d.key);
      }
    })
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  /* set the CSS */
  
  body {
    font: 12px Arial;
  }
  
  path {
    stroke: #ccc;
    stroke-width: 2;
    fill: none;
  }
  
  .axis path,
  .axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-width: 1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  }
  
  #legendContainer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    left: 10px;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 490px;
    width: 110px;
  }
  
  #legend {
    width: 90px;
    height: 200px;
  }
  
  .legend {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-anchor: left;
  }
  
  .legendcheckbox {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  #showAll {
    position: absolute;
    top: 600px;
    left: 880px;
  }
  
  #clearAll {
    position: absolute;
    top: 600px;
    left: 950px;
  }
  
  input {
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background: #999;
    border: 0;
    color: #fff;
  }
  
  #inds {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
  }
</style>

<body>

  <!-- load the d3.js library -->
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <select id="inds">
    <option value="2020" selected="selected">2020</option>
    <option value="2019">2019</option>
    <option value="2018">2018</option>
  </select>
  <div id="legendContainer" class="legendContainer">
    <svg id="legend"></svg>
  </div>
  <div id="showAll">
    <input name="showAllButton" type="button" value="Show All" onclick="showAll()" />
  </div>
  <div id="clearAll">
    <input name="clearAllButton" type="button" value="Clear All" onclick="clearAll()" />
  </div>

</body>
```

What I expect is to show data of the student's total in all classrooms with the x-axis (month), the y-axis (number), and the dropdown (year). Can you help me? Thank you